# Why the degree change of the following polar form

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

From the following image:
[image]

Why was $\theta$ changed to 3.08 instead of -3.12? Confused about that point.

Details about the image:
converting rectangular form to polar = $5^5$  ∠ $5 * -0.64$

Comment: What is that after the very first equality sign?? Is that $\;54\;$, or a $\;5\;$ followed by a sign like $\;\angle\;$ ...or what? What does that $\;0.64\;$ mean? How, where and why is that equality true?

Comment: Edited the question, that is indeed a  ∠ sign, and the -0.64 is the angle multiplied by the power 5, the equality is true due to the polar conversion method

Comment: I think using decimals rather than exact numbers (e.g. multiples of $\pi$) is confusing things here (and by rounding too early, you've lost a lot of accuracy). Angles do not change if you add multiples of $2\pi$ - that is presumably what is changing from $3.08$ to $-3.12$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\theta+2\pi = \theta$. However, the answer should be $3.07$.